# How do I make the desktop view responsive across even larger screens?

Tags: wordpress, web, frontend, responsiveness, divi

I made a website for a client using Wordpress (Divi) and it’s mobile responsive and beautiful. I thought I was done with the project until I sent the client a link to make revisions was when I discovered that the elements of the website are all scattered (he uses the latest MacBook) the whole thing is small and all but when I check on a different laptop in my workspace, it’s perfect. I’ve been really puzzled on how to solve this issue, any suggestions?

I tired to make the elements bigger for desktop but it still doesn’t cut it.